# I am trying to iterate over an Array in Postman Tests tab, This Array key has spaces in it

Tags: postman

Below is the request

```
{
    "quote": {
        "AdpPrefill": "N",
        "AuditFrequency": "Annual",
        
    },
    "OOSE revisions": [
        {
            "Order": "1",
            "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120003"
        },
        {
            "Order": "2",
            "Reference": "P01WK0000014120004"
        },
        {
            "Order": "3",
            "Reference": "P01WK0000014120005"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to iterate the "OOSE Revisions" Array and want to get the latest "Reference", In this case it should be "P01WK0000014120005".

Comment: here is the full request :-

Comment: {
    "quotePolicy": {
        "AdpPrefill": "N",
        "AuditFrequency": "Annual",
        
    },
    "OOSE revisions": [
        {
            "Order": "1",
            "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120003"
        },
        {
            "Order": "2",
            "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120004"
        },
        {
            "Order": "3",
            "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120005"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
let users_len= jsonData.object["OOSE revisions"].length;
for (let i = 0; i < users_len; i++) {
    businessDesc = jsonData.jsonData.object["OOSE revisions"][i].EntityReference;
   
} getting read properties of undefined (reading 'OOSE revisions') error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok You kind of are moving towards the right way, but you are not right there yet.

Let's break your problem into bite size pieces.

here's your data

```
{
  "quotePolicy": {
    "AdpPrefill": "N",
    "AuditFrequency": "Annual",
  },
  "OOSE revisions": [
    {
      "Order": "1",
      "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120003"
    },
    {
      "Order": "2",
      "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120004"
    },
    {
      "Order": "3",
      "EntityReference": "P01WK0000014120005"
    }
  ]
}
```

first we will have to access the object `OOSE revisions`. We could do something like this.

```
 const revisions = jsonData['OOSE revisions'];
 const revisionsLength = revisions.length;
```

this now contains all the revisions that you fetched and its length

We would also need a container `entityReference` for latest EntityReference and also some constant `maxOrder` to compare the order to.

now we need to loop through the revisions and get the latest revision

```
 let maxOrder;
 let entityReference;

 for (let i = 0; i < revisions.length; i++) {
   const currentOrder = revisions[i].Order;
   if (maxOrder === undefined || currentOrder > maxOrder) {
     maxOrder = currentOrder;
     entityReference = revisions[i].EntityReference;
   }
 }
```

during the loop, if `maxOrder` is `undefined` or the `currentOrder` is greater than `maxOrder`, then the `maxOrder` and `entityReference` are updated accordingly ending in the `entityReference` to have the correct value.

```
 console.log(entityReference); // "P01WK0000014120005"
```

---

The way I did is OK, but very convoluted, hard to understand and not very elegant.

You can achive the same result using modern JavaScript methods like maps, filters, etc.

Here's how you do that:

We start out with something like this.

```
 const revisions = jsonData['OOSE revisions'];
```

Then get the latest Order from the object (assuming that the `Order` numbers are incremental and the largest one is the latest one. By mapping through the `revisions` and finding the largest number using `Math.max` we could do something like

```
const maxOrder = Math.max(...revisions.map(revision => Number(revision.Order)));
```

Now that we have the largest/latest number of `Order`, all we have to do is filter the array and get the `entityReference` of the order matching the largest/latest `Order`

```
const entityReference = revisions.find(revision => Number(revision.Order) === maxOrder).EntityReference;

 console.log(entityReference); // "P01WK0000014120005"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Alot Man :), I really appreciate your response.